# Compound subjects, objects or verbs with no conjunction

Tags: grammar

Example:
"...that some morning, as by magic, **all books, pictures, records, chairs, beds, curtains, utensils, keepsakes** would drain away..."

The compound subject in this clause has no conjunction, sounds funny, and seems incomplete without 'and'. I notice this a lot in E.B White's writing and just assume it's legit because of who it is.

Are conjunctions optional?

Comment: Given that it's E. B. White, even if it looked wrong to me I wouldn't admit it.  (But it's perfectly fine as written.)

Comment: What you have is a list of nouns, all the subject of the sentence, all in apposition to each other.  If you were to put in the word "and," that would suggest that the list is complete as to what drained away, nothing else was included.  Making an appositive list without the "and" suggests that more things could be added to the list, but you choose to end it here.  It's kind of an open structure, and it's a hallmark of E.B. White's prose style.

Comment: I'd certainly prefer another ellipsis. Though an 'and' wouldn't really work (as deadrat implies, too prosaic / listy), the lack of anything after the list sounds too businesslike. But we're talking style/s rather than 10 Commandments here.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of style.  It's supposed to sound different from an inventory; White wants to invoke the image of a hoped-for vortex of objects that would disappear like water swirling down a drain.  A conjunction would interrupt the list and the imagined flow.

Answer (score 0):

I would have put an "and" instead of the comma before "keepsakes", but that's just my personal taste. I do not think it is obligatory. So in my opinion the phrase is correct.